# Мониторинг web-services Java

Tags: java, веб-программирование, веб-сервер, service, мониторинг

Разрабатываю проект мониторинга веб сервиса на Java, но появилось куча вопросов, на которые я не нашёл ответа в сети. Я могу копаться в JVM вытаскивая данные CPU памяти и прочее, но как к примеру отслеживать запросы и ответы к сервису(от кого, что,когда). Ничего путного с примерами кода не нашёл. Посоветуйте что.

Comment: Ну, для полного мониторинга вам может потребоваться такой замечательный интрумент, как ``bpftrace``. Без него никакого нормального мониторинга и быть не может.

Comment: а что на счёт запросов к сервису (HTTP)

Comment: ``bpftrace`` позволяет и это тоже.

Comment: можно плизз примеры или ссылки я что то поискал и ничего не понял

Comment: можно: http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2018-10-08/dtrace-for-linux-2018.html

Comment: а есть что  по проще?

Comment: Есть! Готовые решения: гуглите "Free Linux Server Monitoring and APM solutions for SysAdmins".